# When click home navigation, extra space is created

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having an issue where when I click on the logo on the top of my site to go to the homepage, a giant extra space is created below the slider.  You can see what I mean by going [here](http://blue-otter-host.com/ncc/NCC/resources.php) and then click on the "SKANSKA" logo on the top of the page to go back to the homepage.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When I click on the logo, everything looks fine to me. Could you provide a screengrab of the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the browser size needs to be below 1200px to see the issue.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Ya, ya, ya...thanks to jonathanmcdaniel for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after playing with the site for a minute, I realized you meant when the site is re-sized for mobile you see the issue. I resolved the issue by removing max-width: 100% on

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1220px)
.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively it seems you can set the display to none in:

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

After editing the main css file I could not see any other issues that this had on the other versions of the site even though it is a global style.